# Как преобразовать string в char?

Tags: c++, строки, char, преобразование

Есть произвольная строка не больше 25 символов. Например **"wo1fram"**
Как преобразовать ее в массив char[255]?
Чтобы потом с char можно было работать как с полноценным массивом символов, оканчивающимся нуль-символом.

Comment: Для этого есть функция-член [data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут, видите ли, есть два решения.

Одно - если вам надо только читать эту строку, или там, поменять в ней пару символов - но не менять ее размер (так что всякие `strcpy` отменяются) - то можно воспользоваться функциями [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) и [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). Очень рекомендую внимательно почитать описания, а главное - ограничения, накладываемые этими функциями.

И другое - если нужно работать с ней как со строкой в стиле С со всеми возможностями - то просто скопируйте ее в массив, типа

```
char buf[255];
strcpy(buf,s.c_str());
```

или

```
char * buf = strdup(s);
```

Примерно так.